# Unloading Filter Widget from Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Anyone know how to unload the filter widget without destroying tablesorter and re-enabling it without filter widget ?

This is the code I am using which is pretty bad and bulky.

```
<a href="#" data-active="1" class="togglefilter btn btn-primary">Toggle Filter</a>


$(function(){
        $(".togglefilter").click(function(){
            var active = $(this).data('active');
            if(active == 1 ) 
            {
                $("table").trigger('destroy');
                    $("table").tablesorter({
                            theme : "bootstrap",
                            widthFixed : true,
                            headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // new in v2.7. Needed to add the bootstrap icon!
                            widgets : ["uitheme","zebra"],

                            widgetOptions : {
                                zebra : ["even", "odd"],
                                filter_reset : ".reset"
                            }
                });
                $(this).data('active', 0);  
            }
            else 
            {
                $("table").trigger('destroy');
                $("table").tablesorter({
                            theme : "bootstrap",
                            widthFixed : true,
                            headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // new in v2.7. Needed to add the bootstrap icon!
                            widgets : ["uitheme", "filter", "zebra"],

                            widgetOptions : {
                                zebra : ["even", "odd"],
                                filter_reset : ".reset"
                            }
                });

                $(this).data('active', 1);
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/787#issuecomment-68942532), using the [`refreshWidget` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#refreshwidgets) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e3V9V/196/)).

```
var $table = $("table").tablesorter({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    widthFixed: true,
    headerTemplate: "{content} {icon}",
    widgets: ["uitheme", "filter", "zebra"],
    widgetOptions: {
        filter_reset: ".reset"
    }
});

$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('nofilter');
    var widgets = ['uitheme', 'zebra'],
        noFilter = !$(this).hasClass('nofilter');
    if (noFilter) {
        widgets.push('filter');
    }
    $table[0].config.widgets = widgets;
    // refresh widgets
    $table.trigger('refreshWidgets');
    // hide filter reset button
    $('.reset').toggle(noFilter);
});
```

Please note, that this code does not work with the original version of tablesorter.